# summary of the entire integers

Tags: javascript, integer

DHTML page which accepts user input into the text field as integers. when the user pressed the "Display" button, your function created in javascript should able to display the sum of the entire integers in an alert message.

**Example**

Input :

```
"21547524"
```

Output:

```
"2+1+5+4+7+5+2+4 = 30"
```

Comment: @RASG In all fairness, he says it is homework :)

Comment: damn right... my eyes are trained not to see obsolete tags :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var input="21547524";
var additions=input.split('').join('+');
alert(additions+' = '+eval(additions));
```